# grep string without anything surrounding it

Tags: count, grep

I have a directory with multiple files, let's call these 1.txt, 2.txt, etc. Each file consists of 3 columns: an ID, a lat, and a lon. Unfortunately, some of the ID's may also be numbered (e.g., 1346, 248, 67912, etc.). I am trying to count the number of instances a station ID occurs among all files (1.txt, 2.txt, etc.) based on a master file (masterfile.txt). So far I have:

```
while IFS='' read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
cat * | grep -w -c $line >> counting_filename.txt
done < masterfile.txt
```

Which works great. However, if the lat and/or long contain the particular ID, this will also count. For example, if I am looking for the station ID of 4575, if there is a lat of '47.4575' or a lon of '-77.4575', these will also go towards the count. Therefore, there are two solutions I could think of that I can't figure out:

1) Just grep the first column of instances, or

2) grep while NOT including the leading '.'

For example:

```
1.txt
4575 39.4575 -77.51
5010 38.3498 -78.4575
LAMS 38.4444 -78.3126

2.txt
3124 39.1010 -79.4575
4575 39.4575 -77.5010
PAOQ 39.2222 -78.0032
```

If I ran the above command, I would get a count of 6 for 4575, 2 for 5010, 1 for LAMS, 1 for 3124, and 1 for PAOQ.

What is desired is: 2 for 4575, 1 for 5010, 1 for LAMS, 1 for 3124, and 1 for PAOQ.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your grep isn't looking for any pattern at all, did you forget to add it here?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `grep -c "^$line "`?

Comment: Yes melpomene! I knew it was something simple but couldn't find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tools - a small, simple awk script will be far more robust, efficient, and portable than a mixture of shell loops, read, grep, etc.

It's not clear what masterfile.txt is for as from your example it looks like this is all you need:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (id in cnt) print id, cnt[id]}' 1.txt 2.txt
LAMS 1
PAOQ 1
3124 1
4575 2
5010 1
```

If you need masterfile.txt to list a specific set of IDs rather than just producing counts for all IDs as above then you can do that too:

```
$ cat masterfile.txt
4575
3124
PAOQ
BLAH

$ awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$1];next} $1 in ids{cnt[$1]++} END{for (id in cnt) print id, cnt[id]}' masterfile.txt 1.txt 2.txt
PAOQ 1
3124 1
4575 2

$ awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$1];next} $1 in ids{cnt[$1]++} END{for (id in ids) print id, cnt[id]+0}' masterfile.txt 1.txt 2.txt
BLAH 0
PAOQ 1
3124 1
4575 2
```

I added BLAH to show the different options you have of handling an ID from masterfile.txt that doesn't appear in your other files.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! However, the output is not sorted alphabetically so I had to add the sort option. Otherwise, this is much, much better.

Comment: There's no indication in your question that the output had to be sorted or, if it did, what sort ordering to use and the `What is desired` line in your question shows output that is not sorted in any obvious way. It's important when asking question to provide **the** output you want and explain the order if some kind of sorting is required.